# Is there a specific way to open a web link at a certain time in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that opens a zoomlink at a specific time and date.  im not sure why it is not working when I try to test it out one minute from now. Specifically when i tun it from the shell nothing really happens, and when I run it through the terminal I just get "waiting, the current time is" when the specified time comes.

```
import webbrowser

import time

link = input ("zoomlink")

alarm = input("16:25:00")
 
Current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") 
  
while (Current_time != alarm):
    
    print ("Waiting, the current time is " + Current_time  )
    
    Current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
if (Current_time == alarm):
    
    print ("Starting Lecture")
    
    webbrowser.open('zoomlink')
```

Edit: the program will work iff you delete the input() from link and alarm.
so basically do

```
link = "zoomlink"

alarm  "16:15:00" 

#the time is 24 hour time as HH/MM/SS
```

there is a code below that is more concise than this.

Comment: You're not initialising the `webbrowser` variable anywhere

Comment: my bad, I wasn't sure how to format my code on here. I initialize using import webbrowser,

Comment: Did you try `webbrowser.open(link)`?

Comment: And what output did you get?

Comment: I am at the very end. I am using 'webbrowser.open(www.google.com)'  The problem is that when the specified time comes nothing happens at all, all it says is "waiting, the current time is"

Comment: why are the variables `alarm` and `link` set as `input()` instead of a constant value? That blocks your code since `input()` will wait for user input before setting the value of that variable

Comment: because I am very dumb. While I do know something about r and stata I know nothing about python and so I went to the web and blindly followed an example. The code now works and I am editing my post now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that seemed to work:

```
import webbrowser

import time

link = 'www.google.com'

alarm = '00:59:30'
 
Current_time = '00:59:15' 
  
while (Current_time != alarm):
    
    print ("Waiting, the current time is " + Current_time  )
    
    Current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
if (Current_time == alarm):
    
    print ("Starting Lecture")
    
    webbrowser.open(link)
```

The function `input` waits for user input before setting the variable it is assigned to, so your comparison was always failing.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why input() doesn't work but that is a thing I should figure out.